# Blank spaces show as a question mark

Tags: tinymce, encoding

I have a client who wanted to restore her old website from 5 years ago with a very small budget. I suggested that she at least uses Wordpress for CMS and now she has a limited editing capability of a portion of the text on each page. We kept all the old php files for the front end and just request the Wordpress content for the left column of the page.

Now, all extra blank spaces that were in the text show up as question marks inside a black diamond. They show as proper blank spaces in Wordpress editor, and in PHPmyAdmin. Our old pages all have UTF-8 encoding.

What I am confused about is that when I enter a double space in Wordpress now, the "new", just made double spaces **also** come out as question mark on the front end but display as space in MySQL. Shouldn't TinyMCE make `"&nbsp;"` for this? [image]

Comment: Those are control characters that got shoved into the document, possibly from editing the content in Word or some other word processor rather that a proper text editor.

Comment: No, as I mentioned, when I type a double space in TinyMCE it still comes out as a question mark. I am not copying and pasting from Word.

Comment: What is the collation on the database? Or on relevant tables?

Comment: utf8_general_ci

Comment: I am really confused about multiple blank spaces in MySQL text field transferred to HTML. What exactly happens with them? HTML needs '&nbsp;' for them to show correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has solved my issue

```
mysqli_query ($connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707792/issue-with-utf-8-encoding-using-php-mysql

Comment: Interesting. While I don't know the specifics of the problem this does suggest that my encoding suspicion was on the right track.